# How to get total sum of an invoice with the price of the products in another table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a few tables in SQL:

1. Customers table with the customer code, address
2. Products table with the product code, name, and prices
3. Invoices table with invoice codes, customer codes
4. Invoice lines with invoice code, line numbers, product codes and product quantities

I'm trying to get the the total sum of an Invoice by the Invoice codes from the Invoice Lines table, and because some products have more than one quantity, it doesn't go through accurately.

First i thought i could put each quantity of the product as an entry on its own, not have the quantity part on the table, and use select sum. it's not really viable for the long run, and surely there's a better way.

Comment: Welcome at [so]. Please take the [tour] first. Also read [ask]. After these come back and ask your question(s). As your current question is, this won't be answered.

Comment: There is nothing logically wrong with invoice line table having many entries for the same product code. As well as sample data please publish your query code.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(li.Quantity_Col * p.Price_Col) AS 'Invoice Total'
FROM InvoiceLines li
INNER JOIN Products p ON li.ProductCode = p.Code
WHERE li.InvoiceId = 'sample_value'
```

Where:

1. `Quantity_Col` is the name of the column in the invoice lines table where you store the quantity of each line item,
2. `Price_Col` is the name of the column from the invoice lines table
3. `InvoiceLines` is the table where you store the invoice lines
4. `Products` is the table where you store your products data
5. `ProductCode` is the FK in the invoice lines table to the products table
6. `Code` is the code of the product in the products table
7. `InvoiceId` is the name of the column you use as FK to the invoices table
8. `sample_value` is a placeholder for the invoice id after which you want to get the total price.
9. `li` is an abbreviation for the invoice lines table, I like to use abbreviations instead of typing the whole table name. Same for `p` which stands for the products table

Hopefully this helps you. If you need some other help (converting this to a parameterized function for instance), I'll update my answer.

Comment: so i should have the quantity and the price of the products in a same table?

Comment: Not necessarily. I updated the query as I noticed you are storing the price in the products table (and it is good that you do so).

Comment: okay it's fucking amazing.  ran into "the multi-part identifier could not be bound" but think i figured it somehow and now it works. you rock!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Please don't forget to upvote and/or mark it as answer. It might help others that face the same issue see it faster as a solution for themselves too!

Comment: sorry my man i need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, i'll be back here in a year or two with that 15 reputation and do the thing.

Comment: think it's already marked as an answer. have a good one!